# How to create read only tables in MS Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I would like to create a forms in my Access database which will save data to existing tables. This data entry form will save all valid data to the specified tables.

Now I would like to restrict the table from direct entry, i.e. no one can edit/update data directly in tables.

So please suggest me know can I do this.

Comment: You want to create forms to save data but prevent edit/update?

Comment: yes. prevent edit update directly in tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make something readonly AND not readonly. The forms need the tables to be writable.

What you can do is hide the tables, see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/show-or-hide-database-objects-HP005188361.aspx.

If you need the tables for lookups you can make a readonly query based on the table. You have to change the query type to snapshot.